# Debian Apt: architecture not supported by selected mirror

Tags: debian, apt, system-installation, debian-installer

Today I built a new PC, trying to install latest debian 10.9.0, but it always gets stuck on `Apt: architecture not supported by selected mirror`, I tried already 3 different mirrors. The PC is connected to the Internet, ping on google.com works.

Might it be because of a relatively new chipset that is not yet supported in stable version of debian ?

HW:

```
ASUS PRIME H510M-E (Intel H510)
Intel Core i3-10105
8 GB DDR4, 2666 Mhz, DIMM
2x 4TB WD RED Plus
```

Mirrors I used:

```
deb.debian.org
ftp.cz.debian.org
ftp.at.debian.org
```

It is stuck on this for past 2 hours and cancel button does not respond:

[image]

Now I restarted the installation again used deb.debian.org again and everything works so I guess, maybe it was really some problem on the package mirror server.

Comment: Could you add the tested mirrors? please.

Comment: I have added the mirrors I tried.

Comment: Are you able to  continue the installation without configuring `apt`?

Comment: Not really it is stuck forever

Answer (score 0):

It was probably a temporary problem at deb.debian.org that is now resolved and installation went without any problems using same mirror.